# What's the order of __hash__ and __eq__ evaluation for a Python dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashable

I'm trying to understand what Python dictionaries must be doing internally to locate a key. It seems to me that **hash** would be evaluated first, and if there's a collision, Python would iterate through the keys till it finds one for which **eq** returns True. Which makes me wonder why the following code works (test code only for understanding the internals):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return 42

if __name__=='__main__':

    o1 = MyClass()
    o2 = MyClass()
    d = {o1: 'o1', o2: 'o2'}
    assert(o1 in d)      # 1
    assert(d[o1]=='o1')  # 2
    assert(o2 in d)      # 3
    assert(d[o2]=='o2')  # 4
```

Shouldn't the dictionary be unable to find the correct key (returning either 'o1' or 'o2' in both cases #2 and #4, or throwing an error, depending on internal implementation). How is it able to land on the correct key in both cases, when it should never be able to correctly 'equate' the keys (since **eq** returns False).

All the documentation I've seen on hashing always mentions **hash** and **eq** together, never **cmp**, **ne** etc, which makes me think these 2 are the only ones that play a role in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you use as a dict key has to satisfy the invariant that `bool(x == x) is True`. (I would have just said `x == x`, but there are reasonable objects for which that isn't even a boolean.)

The dict assumes that this will hold, so the routine it uses to check key equality actually checks object identity first before using `==`. This preliminary check is an implementation detail; you should not rely on it happening or not happening.

Reasonable objects for which `(x == x) is not True` include `float('nan')` and `numpy.array([1, 2])`.

Comment: so in his example o1 == o1 would return False, but id(o1) == id(o1) would return True?

Comment: I just tried it and o1 == o1 returns False and id(o1) == id(o1) returns True

Comment: @TimurRidjanovic: Yes. `is` is a safer and sometimes more efficient way to compare object identity, though.